# Rotate rtabmap's local_costmap?

Tags: slam, navigation, rviz, rtabmap, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We're using rtabmap and only our local costmap is incorrectly rotated 90 degrees :(. We've tried using TF to rotate a few things with the static_transform_publisher but haven't been successful. Do you have any suggestions? See screenshots:

Incorrect: (the local cost map)
[image: image description]

Correct: (the global cost map)
[image: image description]

Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255157/rotate-rtabmap%27s-local_costmap?/) by [danielsnider](https://answers.ros.org/users/29280/danielsnider/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2017-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

What are the parameters of the local costmap? Which frame it is linked (should be /odom)? The problem could be also the attached frame used on the sensor for the obstacle layer. For example, use `sensor_frame: base_link` instead of `sensor_frame: zed_camera_link`, so that zed point cloud is transformed in base_link before ray tracing in the local costmap.

cheers

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mincrmatt12](https://answers.ros.org/users/29469/mincrmatt12/) on 2017-02-23**:
I'm also on the team, and I can confirm it is set to odom. Then again, this is just testing with a fixed robot, so odom doesn't rotate. Here's a link to our configs: [linky](https://github.com/teamr3/URC/tree/rtabmap_config/rosws/src/rover_rtabmap_config/config)

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-02-25**:
Try changing `sensor_frame: camera_link` in `local_costmap_params.yaml` to `sensor_frame: base_link` (or whatever is your base frame on the robot)

**Comment by [mincrmatt12](https://answers.ros.org/users/29469/mincrmatt12/) on 2017-02-27**:
We've tried that, and it didn't work :(

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-02-28**:
Can you show in RVIZ the point cloud used for the local costmap? How do you setup ZED TFs (see this [post](http://official-rtab-map-forum.67519.x6.nabble.com/zed-camera-frame-won-t-rotate-to-map-td2712.html#a2715) for example)?